# Cognos Analytics 11 - Decimal length won't exceed 8 decimal places

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I'm using Cognos Analytics 11 report studio and I'm trying to bring in a number field with trialing decimals. However, the data only shows up to 8 decimal places.

I know in Cognos 11 you can limit the number of decimals by going to Data > Data Format > Number > Number of decimal places. But even after trying this to increase the number of rendered decimals, I am stuck at 8.

If I paste the generated SQL into my dbms I can verify my data should have at least 13 or more decimal places. At this point im stuck and not too sure what else to try?

**Note:** This is happening with all export types; HTML, Excel, CSV, PDF. All have the same issue.

Comment: What is the desired output type for this report?  Meaning are you hoping to see more decimal places when it's run in HTML\PDF or EXCEL?

Comment: I've tried exporting as all types: Excel, HTML, CSV, PDF, etc. All are showing the limited 8 decimal length

Comment: What dbms are you using?  What is the data type?

Comment: @dougp I am using TOAD for Oracle and the data type is a number

Comment: I'll delete the response given its not considered useful.  I should have asked earlier, is this a list or crosstab? and along Doug's questioning if you look at the properties of this column within the Reporting metadata tree, what does Cognos see this as?

Comment: Oracle's number data type is just a float (which is inherently evil).  Exactly how is it defined - what are the precision and scale.

Comment: @Andrew Float64 precision 0 scale 0

Comment: Ouch!  When you said NUMBER, I assumed something like NUMBER(30,16).  If precision and scale are not defined, that could be the problem.  Like @Andrew says, floats are evil. 
  Since we design our databases, I don't have an example FLOAT column to point Cognos against to test this.  What happens if, within the data item expression, you cast it to a more specific NUMBER() type?

Comment: Docs:  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-75209AF6-476D-4C44-A5DC-5FA70D701B78 states, "Specify a floating-point number using the following form:  NUMBER"  Notice no precision and scale.

Comment: take a look a this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/numericfloat-values-are-limited-15-digits) - it's a couple of years old, but certainly sounds relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen Cognos intentionally exclude decimal length. Like the thread above, I'm also assuming it's because either **1.** The precision is undefined or set to 0 or **2.** The restrictions Cognos Analytics applies when accessing Oracle data.

Keep in mind, something like this is understandable when exporting as a CSV file since it has decimal limitations.

I will look into the two cases above and I'll update my answer if I find anything new. For the interim, if you're needing a solution urgently, you can try some of the following and see if they either fix the issue or give you a potential workaround.

## **Workaround 1: Specifying decimal length under all ancestors**

Typically, specifying the data format number's decimal length should work (excluding CSV). Like you said above, for this you would go to **Data > Data Format > Number > Number of decimal places**.

When specifying the data format, make sure to include all ancestors for the column; it's possible you are leaving one out. If your report is in a list, ensure you are specifying the decimal precision under both the

"**List Column**" [image]and "**List Column Body**" [image]selections.

In theory, if specified for both selectors this should force a higher decimal precision. Keep in mind, for CSV exports will ignore data formatting rules through Cognos. So this will only work as HTML, Excel, PDF.

## **Workaround 2: Converting your data to_char**

If the above solution fails, another possible workaround would be to wrap your item (under the expression definition) in a to_char() and specify the formatting within. It would look something like this **to_char("Column Name", '99.9999999999')**.

[image]

This would account for 10 decimal places though you can really make it however long you need.

What's nice about this workaround is if your value only includes 9 decimal places, even if formatted for 10, you won't receive the trailing 0 on the end and the precision will cut off after its true value. This also works for CSV exporting unlike the above method.

Hopefully one of these helps! I will update this if I find the initial reason for excluding past 8 decimals.

Comment: Thanks for a workaround, to_char works better for me. I did try the first method and it helped. I was only applying to the column body properties. However, still don't know why Cognos isn't automatically picking it up.

Answer (score 1):

Cognos Analytics may be making assumptions about how to handle a `FLOAT`.  You may need to cast the data type deliberately to a more specific type, like `NUMBER(30, 16)`.

Here's a process that assumes some basic object names.  Adjust as needed.

1. Open the query (Report > Queries > Query1)
2. Select the query item that is causing problems and open the expression editor (Properties > Expression or just double-click)
3. If no calculations are being done, the data item expression should look like `[namespace].[querysubject].[queryitem]`.  Use the `CAST()` function to change the data type:  `cast([namespace].[querysubject].[queryitem], numeric(30,16))`

Comment: This works as well, thanks for the workaround